# Нужно через vanilla js реализовать обратный отсчет свойств z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно через js реализовать обратный отсчет свойства  z-index

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Должно получиться так

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item" style="z-index: 4;">Some text</div>
    <div class="item" style="z-index: 3;">Some text</div>
    <div class="item" style="z-index: 2;">Some text</div>
    <div class="item" style="z-index: 1;">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Пробовал через reverse() возвразает ошибку

Comment: А можете приложить код попытки, чтобы участники могли пояснить вам в чем вы ошиблись и исправить ваш код(или предложить лучшую версию)

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле способов достаточно много, но это первый который пришел мне в голову.

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
let length = items.length;

items.forEach(el => {
    el.style.zIndex = length;
    length--;
})
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
    <div class="item">Some text</div>
</div>
```